# Security of requests from android app to server

Tags: php, android, server, request, httprequest

I have an android app and a php server. I send some requests, say for login and other request parameters as required by my app; and the server sends back json which is displayed in the app.

My question is how could I prevent other users from accessing the urls via the browser and getting the results?
Also most of the requests should only execute if the user is logged in. That is taken care of in the app but how in the apis? I can send an auth token to be sent along with further requests, but the same can be get by calling the login api via browser and then sending that login token with other apis. How to handle these situations and prevent access via methods other than the app to get the data?
And also does it matter in case of android apps whether I send the login password encrypted or not from the app? Or should they be encrypted at the server and then stored in the database?

This might be a very naive question, but I couldn't find an existing one here on SO. P.S. I know php apache server is not the best option but the client has an existing php server ready with the apis and he wants to use the same in the app.

Comment: Never did this but what i would do is make a authorization token for the app and send that with every request to see if it is from your app to only allow access from the app. For only allowing request when authenticated i would use a authentication token that is sent back on succesfull authentication. And use https. DONT take my word for it this is just what i would do.

Answer (score 2):

With my experience in writing a JAVA REST API here are the few suggestions I can make,

1> My question is how could I prevent other users from accessing the urls via the browser and getting the results

**ans:** If you want the API to respond to only the requests sent by App, You can sign the request with a unique key which is known only to the app and no  body else.

**For example:** You can generate a string by appending all the parameters you send in a specific order like username+password+param1+param2 and then apply SHA 256 or any of the hashing on that string to generate a unique string and send this string as a Authorization header value :)

At API end because you know the oder of the parameter to join, once you recieve a request regenerate the string using parameter that you have received and apply same hashing on the string and check whether the string you generated matches the request Authorization header value or not and respond to only one with proper Authorization value :)

**How it works :** Being un-aware of Authorization header whenever browser makes a request this vallue will not be there in request hence your APU wont respond.
On the other hand if somebody deliberately tries to track the request and realizes that Authorization header needs to be sent, still wont be able to get response from your API because he will not know the Algorithm used to generate the value nor the sequence of parameter used.

**Use Cases:**
All Outh API's makes use of same pattern. Read OAuth specs for clarity (Though they use ot for different purpose, you can use it to benifit your situation:) ) 
Example of API's : Facebook,Twitter,Google,Linked In and so on :)

2>also does it matter in case of android apps whether I send the login password encrypted or not from the app?

**Ans:**
It does not matter wheteher you use android apps or web browser to make request :) If you are using POST request all your parameters will be encrypted by default :) So dont worry about it :)

3>should they be encrypted at the server and then stored in the database
**Ans:**
Saving a password in a plain text at your data base can lead to many consequences :) So its always better to save encrypted passwords at data base :) As far as usernames are concerned its ok to save them in plain text :)

Extra peice of Info : Make sure all your api's makes use of Secure channel :) I mean make sure your API's are https :)
Hope my suggestions helped :)